# Matplotlib time axis with continuous hours

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to format my x-axis in the way "%H:%M" but with continuous hours (e.g. 2 days = 48:00) like in this example:

#### How I want it

[image: How I want it]

The closest attempt I could made is this example:

#### How it is

[image: How it is]
But the hours doesn't continue.
Here is my simple Code snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import numpy as np

dataY = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
dataX = np.array([0.1,0.5,0.8,1.2,1.3,1.6,1.9,2.1,2.2,2.5]) #Time values like in Excel 1h = 1/24

dataX = dataX +1 #Otherwise it says Error, time values <1
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
timeformat = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
plt.Axes.format_xdata = timeformat
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(timeformat)
plt.xlim(1,4)

plt.plot(dataX,dataY)
plt.ylabel('Y-Values')
plt.xlabel('Time [hh:mm]')

plt.show()
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not plotting any actual dates here. It hence makes sense to not try to format those values as dates. Instead, plot the numbers as they are and use your custom format of choice.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import numpy as np

dataY = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
dataX = np.array([0.1,0.5,0.8,1.2,1.3,1.6,1.9,2.1,2.2,2.5]) #Time values 1h = 1/24

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def timeformat(x,pos=None):
    h = int(x*24.)
    m = int((x*24.-h)*60)
    return "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(h,m)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FuncFormatter(timeformat))

plt.plot(dataX,dataY)
plt.ylabel('Y-Values')
plt.xlabel('Time [hh:mm]')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for the fast reply.